# How to have Linux continue updating while device is locked

Tags: linux, apt, sudo, upgrade

How can I make linux continue any `sudo apt-get upgrade` commands running while my device is locked due to inactivity? I noticed that as soon as it is locked it pauses any upgrades that were running.

Comment: It shouldn't pause. Can you explain a little more [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/721396/100397) what you mean by "_it is locked_". Are you running a graphical interface? Remote session? Does the system hibernate/suspend rather than just lock?